# Getting a value from table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get a value from my table cells using jQuery. I am new to jQuery and I tried many things, but nothing gave me the sought result.
Below are some examples of what I've tried so far.
I simply want to get the text between the `<td></td>` tags.

The DOM looks like this : 
[image]

I tried with :

```
$("tr td:nth-child(3)").text();
```

Which got me :

```
none111none222none111none222
```

I also tried with :

```
$(this).closest('#idDom').text()
```

But this resulted in nothing.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Normally you dont wan to reuse id's, id's are meant to be unique. The id's you have there should be classes

Comment: The first selector is getting that child for every row.  The second selector will work (well, just the `$('#idDom')` is needed) once the HTML is corrected.  You have duplicate `id` values, which makes the HTML invalid, which makes the behavior of the JavaScript undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`$("tr td:nth-child(3)").text();`

This gets you every 3rd `td` in every `tr`, thats why you're getting all that text appended.

---

After you convert all the columns `id` to `class`.. You can do something like this:

```
$('#lblEditDeleteProducts .priceDom').eq(0).text()
```

Using the image in your question, this would return `123`

---

To explain the selector:

`$('#lblEditDeleteProducts .priceDom')` this will return an array of all the elements with class of `priceDom` inside the element with id `lblEditDeleteProducts`.

`.eq(0)` this will return the first element in the array from above

`.text()` this will return the text of the element above

Comment: What happens when I want to access the other row of the table? I have an edit button on each row, which, when pressed fetches the data from the <td>'s. In this case no matter which row i am on i always get the data from the first row. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @RobertRoss Use `$(this).closest("tr").find()` to search for an element in the same row as the element they clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 elements "tr" and you need to specify:

```js
alert($("tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbAtendidos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>   
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1981</td>
      <td>05</td>
      <td>Marc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1982</td>
      <td>06</td>
      <td>Michael</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me. (i changed the id's to classes as suggested above)

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".nameDom").text()
```